# printing duplicated elements into file from linked list

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Define a structure for a node in the linked list
struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node* right;
    struct Node* down;
};

// Function to add a new node to the matrix
struct Node* addNode(struct Node* head, int data) {
    // Create a new node
    struct Node* nextNode = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    nextNode->data = data;
    nextNode->right = NULL;
    nextNode->down = NULL;

    // If the matrix is empty, make the new node the head
    if (head == NULL) {
        head = nextNode;
    }
    else {
        // Add the new node to the right of the last node in the row
        struct Node* temp = head;
        while (temp->right != NULL) {
            temp = temp->right;
        }
        temp->right = nextNode;
    }

    return head;
}

void duplicate2(struct Node* head) {
    // Open the output file
    FILE* file = fopen("output_duplicate2.txt", "w");

    // Traverse the matrix and print each row
    struct Node* row = head;
    struct Node* temp;
    while (row != NULL) {
        struct Node* col = row;
        
        while (col != NULL) {
            temp = col->right;
            if (temp != NULL) {
                if (col->data == temp->data) {
                    fprintf(file, "%d", col->data);
                }
                temp = temp->right;
            }
            temp = temp->down;
            if (temp == NULL) {
                col = col->right;
            }
        }
        row = row->down;
    }   

    // Close the output file
    fclose(file);
}

int main() {
    // Open the input file
    FILE* file = fopen("input.csv", "r");

    // Initialize variables
    int data;
    char ch;
    struct Node* head = NULL;
    struct Node* currentRow = NULL;
    struct Node* prevRow = NULL;

    // Read the input file character by character
    while ((ch = fgetc(file)) != EOF) {
        // If the character is a digit, add it to the current number
        
        if (ch >= 48 && ch <= 57) {
            data = data * 10 + (ch - 48);
        }
        // If the character is a comma, add the current number to the matrix
        else if (ch == ',') {
            currentRow = addNode(currentRow, data);
            data = 0;
        }
        // If the character is a newline, add the current row to the matrix and start a new row
        else if (ch == '\n') {
            currentRow = addNode(currentRow, data);
            data = 0;

            if (head == NULL) {
                head = currentRow;
            }
            else {
                prevRow->down = currentRow;
            }
            prevRow = currentRow;
            currentRow = NULL;
        }
    }

    // Close the input file
    fclose(file);

    duplicate2(head);

    return 0;
}
```

We are given an input csv file like:

```
4,8,45,0
3,56,4,9
12,3,5,90
```

(code should be flexible, this is just an example file, we do not know the initial size)
and expected to write duplicated elements to another file like:

```
4,3
```

Though when I run this code, there is nothing in the output file. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is `head` null when you enter the duplicate2 function?

Comment: I guess so, there were other functions like printing the matrix and counting zeros but I did not involve them at the post. They are working fine, I may edit if it will help @bumbread

Comment: You need to pass in a `struct Node **head` if you want to change `head` (i.e `*head = nextNode;`).  If you don't want to change it then it would be clearer to just do  `return nextNode;` instead of the assignment.

Comment: Use character literals '0' and '9' instead of the magic values, or even better us `isdigit()`.

Comment: fget() returns an int, not a char, which matters for EOF.

Comment: `data` is not initialized.

Comment: Your program segfaults for me at `temp=temp->down`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was getting a segfault on `temp=temp->down` with `temp == NULL`.

`data` is not initialized prior to the loop in `main()` which means the first value read is undefined.

Consider using a csv library.  The parser you implemented in `main()` doesn't implement any error handling (say, header, space in a field or non-numeric data or even negative values or values > INT_MAX etc).

The most straight forward solution is to iterate over your nodes, and record in `data_dup[]` if we found any duplicates (or alternatively count how many times we have seen a given `data` value).  I used an unsorted array that is resized as we process each new unique `data` value.  You could reuse your `struct Node` but it has an extra pointer (`right`/`down`) which would be confusing.  Consider extracting the `data_dup` stuff to a function to make it more readable.  In any case this is a O(n^2) algorithm so it may be too slow for if number of nodes `n` is large (>10k) regarding your "flexible" requirement.  If you care benchmark it.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node *right;
    struct Node *down;
};

struct Node* addNode(struct Node *head, int data) {
    struct Node* nextNode = malloc(sizeof *nextNode);
    if(!nextNode) {
        printf("malloc failed\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    nextNode->data = data;
    nextNode->right = NULL;
    nextNode->down = NULL;
    if (!head)
        return nextNode;
    struct Node *temp = head;
    for(; temp->right; temp = temp->right);
    temp->right = nextNode;
    return head;
}

void duplicate2(struct Node *head) {
    FILE *file = fopen("output_duplicate2.txt", "w");
    if(!file) {
        printf("could not open output file\n");
        return;
    }
    size_t n = 0;
    struct {
        int data;
        int dup;
    } *data_dup = NULL;
    for(struct Node *r = head; r; r = r->down) {
        for(struct Node *c = r; c; c = c->right) {
            size_t i = 0;
            // search to see if we already have seen `c->data`
            for(; i < n; i++)
                if(c->data == data_dup[i].data) {
                    data_dup[i].dup = 1;
                    break;
                }
            // search failed so adding it
            if(i == n) {
                void *tmp = realloc(data_dup, sizeof *data_dup * (n+1));
                if(!tmp) {
                    printf("realloc failed\n");
                    goto out;
                }
                data_dup = tmp;
                data_dup[n].data = c->data;
                data_dup[n].dup = 0;
                n++;
            }
        }
    }
    int first = 1;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if(data_dup[i].dup) {
            fprintf(file, "%s%d", first ? "" : ",", data_dup[i].data);
            first = 0;
        }
    }
out:
    free(data_dup);
    fclose(file);
}

int main() {
    FILE *file = fopen("input.csv", "r");
    if (!file) {
        printf("could not open input file\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Initialize variables
    int data = 0;
    struct Node* head = NULL;
    struct Node* currentRow = NULL;
    struct Node* prevRow = NULL;
    for (;;) {
        int ch = fgetc(file);
        if (ch == EOF)
            break;
        if (isdigit(ch)) {
            data = data * 10 + (ch - '0');
            continue;
        }
        currentRow = addNode(currentRow, data);
        if (ch == '\n') {
            if (head)
                prevRow->down = currentRow;
            else
                head = currentRow;
            prevRow = currentRow;
            currentRow = NULL;
        }
        data = 0;
    }
    fclose(file);
    duplicate2(head);
}
```

and example run yield expected output:

```
$ cat output_duplicate2.txt
4,3
```

Another option as mentioned by @Fe2O3 is store the values in an array then sort it.  This would be an `O(sort)` i.e. `O(n log(n))`.

The fast option would be to use a `set` (check if value is in set, if so it's a duplicate, otherwise add it to set).  It was more code than I wanted to write here (resizable hash table, skip list, red-black tree, etc).  If you use a resizable hash table version of a set it would be an `O(n)` algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

"*What am I doing wrong?*"
You need to traverse the "rows and columns" to find each 'target', then, for that target, traverse the rest of the rows and columns looking for match(es). Then, move on to the next 'target' and search for that one.

For the sake of less typing, use a typedef:

```
typedef struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node* right;
    struct Node* down;
} Node_t;
```

The rest of the code was *tidied*, but was correct.
Here's the traversal search rewritten (and outputting to the console):

```
void duplicate2( Node_t *head ) {
    FILE *fp = stdout; // fopen( "output_duplicate2.txt", "w" );

    for( Node_t *r = head; r; r = r->down )
        for( Node_t *c = r; c; c = c->right )
            for( Node_t *v = r; v; v = v->down )
                /* maybe add something here to advance 'h' somewhat */
                for( Node_t *h = v; h; h = h->right )
                    if( h->data == c->data && h != c )
                        fprintf( fp, "%d,", h->data );

//  fclose( fp );
}
```

This is not the full solution. Advancing the traversing `h` pointer along the horizontal until it is the same as the `c` pointer is left as an exercise. Otherwise, a data row like "4,1,4,2" would report '4' twice...

Comment: Why 4 loops for a 2d linked list?  Not saying it's wrong.

Comment: @AllanWind Hi there! The outer two to 'visit' every node in the 2D array, and the inner two to probe onward from each "target value node" to the end of the array... Starting the inner pair's "column" pointer should silently advance on the first 'v'ertical row until it matches the target node... This is just for fun... :-)

Comment: Hmm... does that algorithm actually work?  How do you avoid printing a duplicate multiple times?  Either you have to mutate the list, or keep a (data, count) around, no?

Comment: @AllanWind The OP's sample data didn't inspire me to strive for variations... :-) If, for instance, 42 appears 3 times, then the 1-2, 1-3 and 2-3 duplications will be reported... The OP can decide if their code should "go silent" once a single duplication is found, or bail out of inner nested loops... At least this does find the 4,3 that the OP was missing... :-)

Comment: @AllanWind Interesting question! If 'n' appears 3 times, the 1-2 pair should be reported. Perhaps finding the 1-3 can be skipped by early termination. But, should the 2-3 pair be reported?? Does one need to keep track of previously found duplicates to silence too many reports? (We know the simple solution would be to transfer all values to an array, sort it and traverse it looking for adjacent equal values... :-)

Comment: It really works well, let me think about the 'h' part. Even if there are 3 or more duplicates of a number, it must show it once. So ghosting the rest after finding one duplicate will work I guess. Any suggestions?

Comment: Simplest way would be to repeatedly 'probe' for duplicates right to the end. A flag can be used to indicate a report of a pair has been made, thereby suppressing repeated reports of the same number. As @AlanWind suggested, add a flag to each node (modify the struct) initialised to 'false'. Set the flag 'true' for all duplicates (reported or supressed.) Then, when scanning forward, simply step past any node marked as having already been determined to be a duplicate.

Comment: I just tested his suggestion, works fine. Thanks a lot for your insights, helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems:

- no check for allocation failure
- the inner loop in `duplicate2` is incorrect: you should use two nested loops to scan the current row and the rest of the matrix.
- elements that are duplicated more than once will be output multiple times.
- in `main`, `data` must be initialized to `0` and `ch` must have type `int`.
- the last line of the file is ignored if it does not end with a newline.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// Define a structure for a node in the linked list
struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node *right;
    struct Node *down;
};

// Function to allocate a new node
struct Node *newNode(int data) {
    // Create a new node
    struct Node *node = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(*node));
    if (!node) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot allocate node for %d: %s\n",
                data, strerror(errno));
        exit(1);
    }
    node->data = data;
    node->right = NULL;
    node->down = NULL;
    return node;
}

void freeList(struct Node *col) {
    while (col) {
        struct Node *cur = col;
        col = col->right;
        free(cur);
    }
}

void freeMatrix(struct Node *row) {
    while (row) {
        struct Node *cur = row;
        row = row->down;
        freeList(cur);
    }
}

int findDup(struct Node *row, int data) {
    while (row) {
        struct Node *col = row;
        row = row->down;
        while (col) {
            if (col->data == data)
                return 1;
            col = col->right;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

struct Node *getDuplicates(struct Node *row) {
    struct Node *dup = NULL;
    struct Node **dupPtr = &dup;

    while (row) {
        struct Node *col = row;
        row = row->down;
        while (col) {
            int data = col->data;
            col = col->right;
            if (!findDup(dup, data)
            &&  (findDup(col, data) || findDup(row, data))) {
                *dupPtr = newNode(data);
                dupPtr = &(*dupPtr)->right;
            }
        }
    }
    return dup;
}

void printMatrix(struct Node *row, FILE *file) {
    while (row) {
        struct Node *col = row;
        row = row->down;
        while (col) {
            int data = col->data;
            col = col->right;
            printf("%d%c", data, ",\n"[!col]);
        }
    }
}

struct Node *loadMatrix(FILE *file) {
    // Initialize variables
    struct Node *head = NULL;
    struct Node **rowPtr = &head;
    struct Node *currentRow = NULL;
    struct Node **colPtr = &currentRow;
    int data = 0;
    int sign = 1;
    int ch, last = '\n';

    // Read the input file character by character
    for (;;) {
        ch = fgetc(file);

        if (ch == '-') {
            sign = -1;
        } else
        if (ch == '+') {
            // ignore plus sign;
        } else
        if (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9') {
            // If the character is a digit, add it to the current number
            data = data * 10 + (ch - '0');
        } else
        if (ch == ',') {
            // If the character is a comma, add the data to the current row
            *colPtr = newNode(sign * data);
            colPtr = &(*colPtr)->right;
            data = 0;
            sign = 1;
        } else
        if (ch == '\n' || ch == EOF) {
            // If the character is a newline of end of file,
            //    add the data to the current row and
            //    add the current row to the matrix and
            //    start a new row
            if (last != '\n') { // ignore empty lines
                *colPtr = newNode(sign * data);
                colPtr = &(*colPtr)->right;
                data = 0;
                sign = 1;
                *rowPtr = currentRow;
                rowPtr = &(*rowPtr)->down;
                currentRow = NULL;
                colPtr = &currentRow;
            }
            if (ch == EOF)
                break;
        } else {
            // ignore other characters: spaces, letters...
        }
        last = ch;
    }
    return head;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *file = stdin;

    // Open the input file if provided
    if (argc > 1) {
        file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
        if (file == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "cannot open %s: %s\n", argv[1], strerror(errno));
            return 1;
        }
    }

    struct Node *head = loadMatrix(file);

    if (file != stdin) {
        // Close the input file
        fclose(file);
    }

    struct Node *dup = getDuplicates(head);

    // Open the output file if provided
    if (argc > 2) {
        file = fopen(argv[2], "w");
        if (file == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "cannot open %s: %s\n", argv[2], strerror(errno));
            return 1;
        }
    }

    printMatrix(dup, file);

    // Free the list
    freeList(dup);

    if (file != stdout) {
        // Close the output file
        fclose(file);
    }

    // Free the matrix
    freeMatrix(head);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wow it looks amazing, thank you. There is a lot to learn from it. As I don't want to cheat and I've already spent my hours on my not-so-perfect code I will go on from improving it. Once I submit the assignment I will go back to this again